# Multiples tables and relationships

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

What the best way and how to work with multiples tables in iOS project and does FMDB supports relationships between tables?
Should I use Coredata or the FMDB wrapper?

Comment: Code data is one of the best. Easy to use also.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you want to do, you can use either Core Data or FMDB + SQLite.

Basically, if one of the follow is true, I suggest using SQLite.

- Performance is really important
- You already have a huge SQLite database from elsewhere
- You plan on making the database cross-platform somehow

Have a look at [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/SQLite-instead-of-core-data.html) blog post to read about the difference between SQLite and Core Data.

However, in most cases Core Data is a better way to go. Core Data is a great framework that helps you keep your consistency (using object graphs) and is really quite easy to use. It has received a bad rep for its performance, but it is actually not that bad. For instance, over-fetching is a common thing that is used to improve performance. This means fetching lots of data and then filtering out the data you actually want. This works great in iOS devices since their RAM is actually really good these days. Use it!

Also, if you plan on using Core Data, you should understand that it is NOT a wrapper for SQLite. You should not be thinking about tables like you normally would. In Core Data you have an object graph with entities instead of tables.

**Conclusion:**

Use Core Data unless you already have a SQLite database form elsewhere OR performance matters a lot (and I mean a lot).

Answer (score 1):

There is no one good question for this. It's depends on project.

In my opinion if you have already some data which you want to import to the application, and you will facing huge amount of data in your database, you should go for pure `sqlite` (and maybe FMDB).

If you are connecting to REST, want to use TableViews, starting from empty database `CoreData` will right answer for you.

FMDB is only a wrapper on `sqlite` so it will have relations, because sqlite has.